Best way to pass data between threads when using BackgroundWorker class
I have a Winforms app that I'm developing. There is a time-consuming task that the user will initiate by pressing a button. I don't want my UI to freeze and I also want information to continuously come back from that task that can then be used to update UI controls and a progress bar.
I researched and it looks like the BackgroundWorker class is intended for these types of use cases. However, I looked at many examples and it's unclear to me how to pass data from my worker thread back to my UI thread. Most examples simply focus on passing back a percentage complete number via the ReportProgress() method, and the ProgressChanged event handler is where we are told to interact with the UI.
Here is what I've done so far:

Created a background worker reference via the components toolbox called "backgroundWorker1"
Created a button-click event handler for the UI button control
Inside the event handler I call backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
Implemented my time-consuming task inside the backgroundWorker1_DoWork() method.

The literature says not to try to interact with the UI inside the DoWork() method, but rather via the ProgressChanged event handler. But how do I pass the data to that event handler so that it can update the UI controls?
Any insight is appreciated. Here is a sample of the code, some of it is pseudo-code.
My worker method:
private async Task<bool> runAttenRoutineAsync()
    {
        bool success = false;
        double measurement = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < STEPS_MAX; i++)
        {
            double setPointLow = (i * 0.5) - 0.1;
            double setPointHigh = (i * 0.5) + 0.1;

            do
            {
                    //Acquire measurement from equipment
                    // success = someFunction(out measurement);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
                while (measurement < setPointLow || measurement > setPointHigh);
            }

            update_controls_sliders(someGlobalInt);
            label1.Text = ((double)(someGlobalInt) / 20).ToString("0.00");

        }

        return success;
    }

Main (UI) thread:
private async void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //various functions to set up test equipment

        await workerRoutineAsync();

        return;
    }


Looks like you failed to look at the second overload of ReportProgress. In this overload https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress?view=net-8.0#system-componentmodel-backgroundworker-reportprogress(system-int32-system-object) you have the possibility to pass an object for the UserState properties of the ProgressChangedEventArgs. This object could contain the data that you want to handle in the ProgressChanged event

You could send some complex user state along with the progress:

        
        private Dictionary<int, string> _backgroundSteps = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            [1] = "Preparing frobbles for {0}",
            [2] = "Executing wibbles for {0}",
            [3] = "Cleaning up {0} frobbles and {1} wibbles"
        };

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //prepare frobbles
            var database = new DB();
            var preparingFor = database.GetUser();

            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(1, new string[] { preparingFor });

            PrepareFrobbles();

            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(2, new string[] { preparingFor });

            ExecuteWibbles();

            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(3, new string[] { database.CountFrobbles().ToString(), database.CountWibbles().ToString() });

            CleanUp();
        }


        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            _statusLabel.Text = string.Format(_backgroundSteps[e.ProgressPercentage], (string[])e.UserState);
        }

Here I'm using the progress to just count a 3 step process, passing some varying state along with the message, and simply updating a label with a message.. I could get a lot more involved in the ProgressChanged, using conditonal logic to do different things depending on the int passed, making better use of the state object etc..
Or I could not even use the overload of ReportProgress that takes a state, and just report the int, cycling a highlight through some panel of labels showing what stage the process was at etc.. It's quite open as to how you use this. If you were deleting 100,000 database records, you're free to pass the count as the percentage progress and have a ProgressChanged handler like statusLabel.Text = "Deleted "+e.ProgressPercentage+" records" - it won't explode if you pass numbers outside the range 0 to 100 as the percentage

These days we'd probably use Task Async Pattern instead, and have our method that does work look like this:

    private async Task DoSomeLongWork(){

        statusLabel.Text = "Preparing frobbles";

        await PrepareFrobblesAsync();

        statusLabel.Text = "Executing wibbles";

        await ExecuteWibblesAsync();

        statusLabel.Text = "Executing wibbles";

        await CleanUpAsync();

    }

The code executing this is the UI thread if you havent put any other multithreading into your app, so it's safe for it to set the text of the label.
The UI thread doesn't get tied up doing the long work of preparing the frobbles and executing the wibbles, which would cause your app UI to freeze; that work is handed off and while the task that controls it is being awaited the UI thread disappears off back to the place it came from to get on with its normal job of drawing the UI.
When the frobbles are finished being prepared (for example) and the task is done, the UI thread resumes executing of this code from just after the await PrepareFrobblesAsync, sets another status, then disappears off again while it awaits the execution of the wibbles etc

Thanks for your answer but I don't fully understand this. My use case is simpler, I am basically trying to pass various interger values back to the UI. I created a class that has a bunch of integer properties. This class is called UserState. I am passing an instance of this class in ReportProgress. But when I try to "unpack" it in progress changed I'm not seeing how to do that. In ProgressChanged I do something like: int n = e.UserState.IncrementValue; but this doesn't seem possible. I see that I can pass my unique object, but not sure how to extract its properties on the other end.

See where I pass a string[] array in when I call ReportProgress.. It comes through as a plain object (It's very old tech y'see) when it's presented in e.UserState so it needs casting back to what it really is (i cast it to a string array before I pass to Format) before one can use any named properties on it. If your "class of integer properties" is declared like class MyIntProps and you call ReportProgress(1, new MyIntProps(){ IncrementValue=123}) then you'll have to do var mip = e.UserState as MyIntProps then you can mip.IncrementValue no problem

Chiefly, remember that this thing (BackGroundWorker) is really old; most stuff in winforms is, so it uses object a lot as a "way to pass anything" as it harks from a time before we had generics.. You'll see it all over, like event handlers: Button1_Click(object senger, EventArgs e) - that sender could be a button, label, panel, form, http thing, whatever.. In the very old days the only way to "pass any varying thing" was to use object, so you always needed a cast to turn the "button that looks like an object" back into a button.Casting looks like: (Button)sender or sender as Button

Also, if I go the route of using Tasks, how do I do it with the WinForms button click event handler? Because when the user presses the button to start the process, it will go to my button click event, which by design cannot be of return type Task. My plan was to run the code in that event handler and use await statements for functions that return tasks, but the code editor is telling me that this calling function must also return Tasks in order to use the await keyword. I've experienced this before with Tasks, it feels like a chicken and egg endless loop. What am I missing here?

Windows Forms event handlers are one of the few places that people won't (shouldn't) get up in your tree if you declare public async void Button1_ClickAsync(...) - you'll be able to write await MyLongRunningWorkAsync() inside the event handler.

I tried to implement this, but having few issues. I made my event handler public async void as suggested above. This even handler calls the async worker function using await. The worker function contains a nested loop that runs for a while... it has to interact with test equipment. At each iteration of the outer loop in the worker function, I have statements to update several UI controls. The slider controls are updated to show their new values (positions), but the label controls (label.text = "foo") are never updated in the UI. What am I doing wrong here, why is one updated and not the other?

I also tried the approach of having the outer loop in the event handler function (UI thread) and awaited the worker function which was simply the inner loop of my process. The worker function would update global variables, then in the outer loop (UI thread) it would pull those globals and update the control labels. But to no avail.

Really need to see the code to understand. Can you post it or a smaller clip of it that still reproduces the problem ?

I have updated my original post with code.

I have now resolved this. The issue is that I needed delegates to go update the UI elements. I also had a Thread.Sleep call inside my async worker function which was blocking. I replaced it with an await Delay call.

The issue is that I needed delegates to go update the UI elements - probably not if the code is as posted in the question. It all runs on the UI thread. Making your runAttenRoutineAsync async/awaitable doesn't automatically mean it runs on an non-UI thread.. It means that the UI thread is allowed to leave without finishing it

I also had a Thread.Sleep - yes, and in a loop, so you trapped the UI thread into your code and never released it to go back to its work drawing the UI. Changing this Thread.Sleep for await Task.Delay(100) would allow it to go back frequently, and spend at least 100ms doing other stuff

Side note, please name your methods in PascalCase, not camelCase
